# Are job offers spam?

Tags: discussion, support, spam

Every few weeks, we seem to get a question which is nothing more than:

> I need a developer to do X, if you are interested, please contact me
>   at YYY@ZZZ.com

Unquestionably a terrible, off-topic question that should be downvoted, closed, and left to burn in hell (or the terrible question equivalent).

My question is; are these questions spam? They aren't necessarily an advertisement, but they *are* self-promotional. Should we flag them as such?

Comment: Yes they are spam of course, and I've been already wondering about your reaction [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791099/developing-a-school-management-software). Don't encourage such stuff, it's OT.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I realize that; and I was not trying to encourage it. I was trying to point them to where they could post such a request. I asked the question because I was not sure if I should be casting a flag against the post.

Comment: I was curious to know this myself, because I have seen a lot of these job offer posts and wasn't sure whether I should flag them or not. Thanks for this post.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Your welcome; I would have posted it sooner but hadn't thought of the spam flag for these posts yet. Glad it was able to help someone else.

Comment: @pnuts The disclosure piece is important; but a post that says "Im an employee of X company; you should try our Y product!" is still spam. The primary intent is *promotional*.

Comment: @pnuts The disclosure piece is important when the "spam" is *relevant*. Perhaps you actually work for a company that makes a library that solves the problem in the question. In this case, mentioning it as a solution is perfectly fine, as long as you disclose your affiliation (just don't do this a lot!)

Comment: @pnuts "relevant" spam is still spam (and should be flagged as such) if its done repeatedly (often with "seed" questions) or done without disclosure. Spam is obviously spam if its not relevant, even if there *is* disclosure. The wording may not be perfect, but it makes enough sense to me (except for job offers, hence this question :) ).

Comment: I recently flagged such a question as _rude or abusive_, because such job offers are clearly abusing the system. Since _spam_ and _rude or abusive_ flags (both red flags) seem to be handled (at least almost) identically, the flag was marked _helpful_, so I assume this is a viable option other than a _spam_ flag.

Comment: somewhat similar question at MSE: [Where to post free-time job offers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246886/165773)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Yes, they are spam. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to get answers to programming questions, not to solicit developers for work.

Stack Overflow used to have a [Careers site](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/products), but this is no longer in operation. Employers will have to look at advertising elsewhere, such as with recruiters, job boards, and social media. Reddit has a lot of tech situations vacant channels.

Comment: But was @BradleyDotNET right or wrong in directing OP to careers in [his comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791099/developing-a-school-management-software)? What is the appropriate action? Flag, downvote, close, comment or any combination of these.

Comment: @GolezTrol I would argue that redirect-commenting is helpful inasmuch as it makes the poster unlikely to attempt a repeat offense: if they find a good alternative site for their request, they're not going to make a similar post in the future. This is even more true of opinionated posts ("go ask on a freeform Q&A site like Yahoo Answers, etc."), but I think it's true to some degree here as well. On the other hand, such comments might encourage the poster to make *other classes* of off-topic posts in hopes of being helpfully redirected again. I don't know which factor is more significant.

Comment: @GolezTrol Here, flagging as spam is appropriate, per this answer. When flagging as spam, the conventional wisdom is *not* to downvote, as a negative score can remove the post from the front page before it attracts enough spam flags.

Comment: @apsillers Good arguments. So: always flag, redirect comment for first offence and no downvotes as not to hide the question from other flaggers. I really didn't think of that last argument, so it's good that you mentioned it.

Comment: Sorry sorry, when (exact date and reason please) did the purpose of Stack Overflow change from "being a database of knowledge in Q&A form" and "to make the web a better place" to "being a place to get answers to programming questions?" Did I miss something?

Comment: @rightføld [Where have you been?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's about what is on-topic and what is not, not about what the site is about.

Comment: The old about page featuring [this image](http://blog.codinghorror.com/content/images/uploads/2008/09/6a0120a85dcdae970b012877705441970c-pi.png) covered it up nicely.