# Why was my spam flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

I recently flagged a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914395/hi-friends-if-u-have-android-source-code-for-e-dairy-project-then-pls-inform-me) as spam which has been subsequently removed through moderation.

Here was the post itself:

[image: spam post]

I believe this post was blatant spam, yet my flag was disputed:

[image]

Up to this point I had a perfect 368/368 flagging history and spent a lot of time trying to make appropriate flags. Where did I go wrong and what could I have done differently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wasn't the mod that handled this, in fact it was automatically handled because of [triage reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6725588) but I'd have done the same if I'd seen this flag too. I'll try to explain my reasoning in detail, but basically I don't think it was spam.

The Q looks is clearly a bad question, but I don't think the person is acting in bad faith - it would be a viable question on many traditional Internet forums, there's no deceit and they're still welcome to ask further questions provided they're good ones.

Most of the real spam we see is pushing handbags/shoes/videostreaming (or a handful of companies with software products that they apparently can only sell via subterfuge). Save the spam flags for the those categories and use downvotes/closevotes for poor quality questions.

Comment: Ok, this right here is making me lose faith in triage reviewers and triage itself ever working. The question "should be improved"? Only one of 4 reviewers thought this crappy excuse for a post is unsalvageable and should be closed? Can we please review-ban the three people who thought "we'll edit this question a little and it's totally fine"?

Comment: @l4mpi this isn't the first or the worst I've seen either (http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6684815), but until there are audits and more of the mechanics around the output from "Should be improved" I'm not overly concerned.

Comment: I remember this post. I hit the close button, but by then it was already too late. The person who asked the question had already deleted it (or  may be a mod removed it like you said). I can't say for sure because I don't have the 10,000 reputation required to tell who did the delete. In any case, the question was deleted may be less than a minute after you took that screenshot. I'm not sure what happens to the review queue when that happens, but may be that just interrupted the review process.

Comment: I appreciate the included reasoning in your answer and I'm comfortable with using the spam flag when appropriate now. Thanks.

Comment: @Flexo How is this case different from: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276249/are-job-offers-spam where the answer was "Job offers are spam"? Its a *little* different in that they are hoping someone already has the code, as opposed to writing it from scratch, but that seems a fine line.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I guess I'm disagreeing then for this instance. The test I want to apply is an inherently subjective judgment of intention, did they believe it would be a reasonable question or simply not care? I.e. should I assume good faith?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: My personal view is that without the offer of money this question could still have been a question (albeit a very bad one). It would have been theoretically possible to answer it by supplying the required code. "I need a developer to do X" would have no answer except people volunteering to do X which is not appropriate. It is a woolly line though that I would certainly expect people to come down on different sides of but that is my view of how those two cases differ.