# voting to close/delete the question because it looks like a lame freelancer job posting

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons, vote-to-delete

[image: a question that goes: "a java applet which will have three text fields and upon user input, input will be shown in a dialogue box. Full prog is needed"]

I have an option to vote this question as "Unsalvageable". First I choose the following option:

> *it should be closed for another reason...* This question does not meet
>   this site's standards and should be closed.

Then I choose:

> *off-topic because...* This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

And in that category I can't see an option that'd let me vote for closing the question because I think whoever asked it believes this is some sort of a freelancing website. It feels like that option should be there, but it's not.

[image]

Am I missing something? Which one should I choose?

Comment: "Too Broad" is a great choice here (back one level from the Off-Topic selections).

Comment: Perhaps "Blatantly off topic"

Comment: @Lex it's NOT blatantly off topic though, it HAS to do with programming. Brad's suggestion of "too broad" seems to be the better solution here

Comment: It isn't about a programming problem or a problem about a tool used for programming. it's off topic. heck, it isn't even a question.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies! I ended up choosing `Unclear what you're asking`. Can't remember now what was the exact title, but it was above the `Too Broad` option suggested above.

Comment: Note that *actual* job postings should be flagged as spam.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thanks I was thinking about doing that, but the `spam` option mentioned only promotional questions, this one doesn't look like one of those.

Comment: Right. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276249/are-job-offers-spam for more. This one would not qualify as spam to me.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Okay, right, you said `*actual* job postings` and I replied `this one doesn't <...>`, sorry about that misunderstanding. Still, even the actual job postings do not seem to meet the `promotional only` criteria, but the question you've linked to seems to cover more or less what I was asking about. Please post it as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @TheSexiestManinJamaica Done!

Comment: From the title of that question, it was obviously copied from a homework assignment or something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, its not really a job posting. Thus, close as the commenters and answers have noted, probably as "Too Broad" ("Unclear what you are asking" is also OK)

However, if it **was** a job posting, please flag it as spam. This is discussed further in:

[Are job offers spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276249/are-job-offers-spam)

Answer (score 8):

Any time you see a question that starts with:

> Write a `<language>` program that `<objective>`

...you're looking at an incredibly **broad** question.  Hence, this is why the "Too Broad" flag works well; it informs the asker that their question needs to be pared down *at the minimum* in order for it to be on topic here.

I wouldn't personally use a custom close reason here, as it indicates that the close reason we want isn't provided.  In this case, the "Too Broad" reason adequately fits, so it should be used.

You will want to be selective in your dismissal, however; there are questions which will contain instructions that read *like* this, but are both salvageable and clearly understandable by other readers.

Answer (score -2):

There are a number of options.

First, this looks like a homework assignment. Which means you can use off-topic with a custom close reason: "it is a homework question that shows no effort at all from the OP."
The lack of effort makes it off-topic; it says clearly in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

I find the custom close reason the preferable way of dealing with homework dumps.

Of course, if the OP had added an MCVE of their attempt at a solution, it would have been another matter entirely.
For this reason, you could choose the off-topic "Questions seeking debugging help" close reason. It is not entirely applicable, as there is apparently nothing to debug yet. But it has the advantage that, when the question is put on hold, the text about how to ask for debugging help is added by the system. And that text contains the message the OP needs to get. It also advises them to add an MCVE, and even provides the link to the MCVE page.

Another option is "Too Broad". It's asking for an entire program to be written. We're here to help people, not to do their work *for* them. And the answering space on Stack Overflow was never meant for entire programs.

"Unclear what you're asking" as you chose to do is also an option. Although technically speaking the question is clear... it's asking to do their homework for them. I prefer the custom close reason or "Too Broad".

Comment: Why use the custom flag when "too broad" fits perfectly?

Comment: @ryanyuyu If people just dump their homework on SO without even trying to solve it themselves, it gives a signal both to the OP and future visitors that this will not be accepted.

Comment: **There is nothing wrong with homework questions.** They just have to be on-topic and sync up with the standards we'd expect from any other question on the site.

Comment: @Makoto Edited my comment to clarify this a bit - the problem is people dumping their homework without even trying. That is below the standards we have. I have no issue with people who try first and then ask for help.

Comment: @S.L.Barth for the "without even trying" too broad is usually still applicable.  Besides, a torrent of downvotes for "lack of research or unclear" will follow any half-baked homework question.