# What is the best way to flag a question looking for a developer to do work?

Tags: discussion

I'm referencing questions where people state the problem they have and say something along the lines of "I'm looking for someone to do this for me"

It's not exactly spam, but it also doesn't really fall into one of the flagging categories anyway. This could also apply to Homework Requests.

Is there some sort of "This type of question is not allowed" flag that is preferred to be used?

Comment: More often than not, _"too broad"_ applies. And a vote down.

Comment: Do not frame homework questions *any* differently than any other question.  They're still valid questions and are subject to the same scrutiny we give any other question here.

Comment: I can see how that would make sense. As they're not exactly asking a question, but requesting work.

Comment: Related: [*Are job offers spam?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276249/are-job-offers-spam)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the question is truly asking us to do their work for them (e.g. "please give me a solution", or "share some sample code"), then flagging it as **Too Broad** is appropriate.

If you're unsure if it should be flagged but believe it to be a poor question anyway, **don't** flag it, and downvote it instead.