# Is a job offer posted as a question considered as "Off topic"?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs, scope

I have used a custom flag to flag a job offer posted as a question since the default flags seemed to not fit the bill in my opinion.

The closest one I could think of was "Off topic", but the Off topic description says it must not be about programming at all, while the job offer technically was about programming which dissuaded me from using that one.

I read the link about flagging that was provided alongside the rejection of my flag and even after that I still would find myself struggling to find a proper fit in the default flags for such a thing.

**EDIT: I am aware the question "Are job offers spam" has already been asked. Even so, it didn't come up as immediate while searching and i did link the post myself merely a couple hours after asking the question and before this had been flagged, i believe this should stay as it asks a different question with a different context and also explains why offtopic may also fit even tho it is not the best category for it. Ultimately i think it is silly that a post i myself linked as reference for my documentation gets cited as proof of this being a duplicate**

Comment: If it has a commercial interest, and job offers do, I’d be inclined to mark it as spam, to get it off the page posthaste. SE has a whole business allowing companies to recruit from the userbase they’ve built. Trying to avoid paying for that service by abusing the free service seems repugnant to me.

Comment: Yes, definitely! i was not aware of how exactly the job offers tab worked since i have never paid attention to it. I guess i was trusting in the good will of these people figuring someone would inform them the job offers are to be posted elsewhere

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't believe you should be using custom flags for off topic posts. Custom flags are for exceptions and should not be used for something as typical as an off-topic post. Although I agree with the post being spam.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The linked question is whether job offers are spam. This question is whether or not they are off-topic. Off-topic and spam are not the same thing.

Comment: @Dukeling yes, i now understand that, i didn't think it was fitting for the offtopic tag as that tag specifically mentions it has to not be related to programming, but it was explained that is intended as practical programming

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A job offer sounds like spam.  That's the appropriate flag to use.

It is also off topic, but a spam flag would be the most appropriate flag.  It's off topic because SO isn't a place for all questions that are somehow related to programming, it's a place for practical programming problems (and even within that context, some types of practical programming problems are still off topic; something being a practical programming problem doesn't mean it's on topic, but something *not* being a practical programming problem means it's going to be off topic for sure), of which a job offer is most certainly not a practical programming problem.  But don't flag it as off topic, use a spam flag, because it's spam.

Comment: I have noticed the question was asked before by using "spam" in the search instead of "off-topic" here [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276249/are-job-offers-spam) it was just unclear to me why the flag was denied, Thanks for the clarification