# What is the right standard flag for question looking to hire somebody

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, declined-flags

While doing triage, I flagged this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441017/i-pay-500-dollars-for-spring-boot-mysql-and-maven-fullcalendar-which-allow-user. From the URL alone you can deduct the content of the question. The question has been removed since. 
I chose "In need of moderator intervention":

> This answer is looking to hire a contactor to code something. It's not spam but also not a question as defined in the help center. – EliteRaceElephant Oct 17 at 22:16
>   declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?

My flag was declined yet the post was still removed.

I have two questions:

1. What is the right standard flag?

I read through the linked FAQ, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review) and its duplicates. I still don't know what the right standard flag is. I find the FAQ and the categories to be confusing. The only thing I learned this far was to skip flags I am not sure how to categorize.

2. I have not been able to do any more review queues since my flag was declined (8 days now). Is it ever coming back?

I feel that I just started to learn how to review and now I am locked out of contributing to SO because a flag was appropriate yet I chose the wrong checkbox.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### 1. What is the right standard flag?

I personally would not have declined your custom flag for the given reason. I can understand how you would have felt that particular question is a bit of an edge case, and thus erred on the side of a custom flag. I prefer not to penalize folks for doing this. I absolutely decline custom flags when there is an *obvious* standard flag, but I don't think this is one of those cases. Apparently another one of the moderators—the one who handled your flag—disagrees with me; *c'est la vie*.

Anyway, if you cannot convince yourself that it is spam (for which the flag would be obvious), the correct standard flag is just one of the "needs to be closed" flags. As to which one…well…the truth is, it really doesn't matter. Don't overthink it.

I would have also entertained a "very low quality" flag on a question like that. Although often misused, the description for that flag states (emphasis added):

> This question has severe formatting or **content problems**. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might **need to be removed**.

The question doesn't have any real formatting issues, but it definitely has irredeemable content problems, and it definitely needs to be removed. VLQ flags are best thought of as "needs to be deleted by a moderator" flags. They should be used to bring total garbage to our attention, things that are in need of immediate deletion. Do not use them on questions that are merely off-topic, too broad, etc.—use closure flags for these and other "normal" cases.

Regarding the applicability of a spam flag…I gotta be honest that the jury is split on that one, too. In [this Meta Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276249/are-job-offers-spam), you see that a former Stack Overflow moderator is on record as saying that job offers like this one are definitely spam. On the other hand, I'm pretty sure there are other Stack Overflow moderators who take a bit more restrictive view of spam, and would decline (or at least dispute) a spam flag on a job offer masquerading as a question. They sort of have a point—it's unlikely that the –100 reputation point penalty that is automatically applied to spammers is appropriate in these cases, which are more than likely attributable to ignorance rather than malice. My personal view is that the reputation penalty associated with spam flags is an implementation detail, and not something that the flagger should be concerned with (or even need to know about). Moderators can mark the spam flag(s) as helpful, yet choose to delete the answer without applying the penalty, and they are in the best position to make this decision, given the abundance of contextual information that is uniquely available to them. In summary, you *might* get a spam flag on posts like this one marked as "helpful", or you might get it declined. If you're overly concerned about declined flags, then err on the safe side and choose a different flag. But…don't be overly concerned about declined flags. The point of flags is to bring potentially problematic things to moderator attention. Your flag accomplished that goal, so it is appreciated.

#### 2. I have not been able to do any more review queues since my flag was declined (8 days now). Is it ever coming back?

The two things are unrelated. The reason you are unable to perform any more reviews (or even see the review queues) is because you are currently banned from reviewing.

You were banned from reviewing by a moderator, with the tipping point being [your decision on this triage item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24340789). You said that "Looks OK", but it definitely doesn't.

Your penultimate review ban was for your decision on [this triage item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24056540), for which you selected "Requires Editing". Although [it is not necessary clear to everyone what this option means](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues), the correct use of "requires editing" is when *other community users* (like you) are able to edit the question into shape. It should *not* be used when the edit needs to come from the original author (e.g., because they need to edit in additional information). If a question is unsalvageable and/or can only be improved by the author, [you should flag/vote to close or delete instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148).

The review ban before that was for your decision on [this triage item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24007461). Pretty sure that one is obvious. What kind of varnish you can use over Minwax Polyshades is *clearly* not a programming question, and thus "Looks OK" is *definitely* the wrong choice.

Review bans can be imposed both manually by moderators and automatically by the system. Automatic bans come from failing [review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work).

Regardless of who imposes a review ban, it is always accompanied by some explanatory text describing the reason(s) for the ban. You should be able to see this message by visiting [the review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review). ([The team *really* needs to make this message more obvious](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351386/make-it-more-obvious-that-youre-review-banned), if review bans are to fulfill their intended pedagogical function. There are too many people like you who are review banned, yet don't know it and certainly don't know why. How can you possibly learn to improve?)

Speaking of learning to improve, we have a couple of FAQ posts on Meta Stack Overflow that are worth reviewing while you're waiting out your review ban. In particular:

- [Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue)
- [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)

Your review ban was imposed on October 18th, and has a duration of 16 days. Thus, it will expire some time around November 3rd. The reason why the duration is 16 days is because you have were banned from reviewing on three previous occasions. The duration of a review ban increases (generally doubling) each time that you are banned.

Comment: Some of the triage items you refer to are since long deleted. I can't see those on SO, as being <10K. Would OP be able to see the content of the deleted questions? Besides that a really great answer!

Comment: This is a perfect example of applying complex legalistic interpretations of rules to a situation where an individual was simply trying to help SE.  They ended up being punished for this ridiculous lawyer-like reading of rules.  A little common sense (the thing SE lacks at present) is what should be used, not literal interpretations of rules.

Comment: @StephenG I'm active and flag on a lot of sites, and while I agree that VLQ would have been better, it's only on SO where you'll be declined for "wrong flag reason" - other sites either accept or both accept and message you that you ought to use a different flag. It's because of SO's (and not Cody's) "we don't have time for your flags attitude" (and I ***do*** appreciate that they are understaffed) that I no longer bother to flag there; the moderators whom declined my last few flags can fill in for me. The "Audits" are also too frequent, so I spend my time on the S**E** sites instead.

Comment: @Luuklag I included the links because, as I understand, users are always able to see *their own* reviews. This change was made in order to further the purpose of review audits/bans being educational tools. So you won't be able to see the review items or the deleted posts, but the person who originally did the review should be able to see them.

Comment: @Stephen I somewhat agree, with a couple of caveats. (1) SO mods  deal with a *huge* flag volume (almost 20k flags in the past week), so there's a motivation to get people to use standard flags. The boilerplate is true: it *does* make it easier for us to sort and prioritize flags, and that's important at our scale. (2) Having a flag declined shouldn't be viewed as a punishment. The decline reason is intended to suggest a tweak to flagging behavior. Nevertheless, confusing in this case, I agree. (3) As annoyed as you may be with SE employees, none of this is coming from them.

Comment: @CodyGray *"As annoyed as you may be with SE employees..."*  Just to be clear I am annoyed with senior managers for pushing an agenda (IMO) of making legalistic and punitive rules instead of trusting our moderators and their common sense with *loose guidelines*.  I would say that ordinary users (like me) need common sense, not rigid doctrine.

Comment: @CodyGray okay, good to know.

Comment: I've had a few Custom Flags declined recently: some, I just accepted, one came with an attached explanation from the mod (telling me I should've used a more appropriate Standard Flag), and others I've raised issue with here on Meta. I'm very satisfied with the discussions and explanations I received in those cases; specifically, the point made here by @Rob that mods on SO are **extremely** busy folks. But, whatever the case, I agree that such declined flags should not be considered punishment, and neither should review bans: it's a learning process!